# couchbase lite support with other server

Tags: android, mongodb, couchdb

Is this possible to have couch base lite on mobile side and server side we use mongodb ?

because we create document in couch base lite and with the help of sync-gateway we can send and receive the request from the couchbase server like :

> Mobile app (with couch base lite)  >>>> gateway >>>> couch base server.

Is there possible to use back end mongodb with couch base lite